# Problems in recovering from a seed of Multibit HD

Tags: multibit, wallet-recovery, multibit-hd

I've installed and created a new wallet in Multibit HD on my PC, I used a seed of 24 words. As far as I understood, with this 24 words I can recover it on a mycelium android, and I should see and be able to spend the bitcoins from both devices.
The problem is that after fresh installing the mycelium on android I choose to recover from seed, enter the 24 words but I can't see my bitcoins. A new wallet with 0 bitcoins appears.
Is it normal? what i don't understand about HD wallets? I thought that both wallets shold be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default MultiBit HD wallet uses an address generation scheme known as BIP32. Mycelium uses an address generation scheme known as BIP44.

BIP44 is what Trezor uses.

HD wallet interoperability is unfortunately a bit thorny. It's normally easier to have two wallets.